# How to prevent multiple function call in JS

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and I need to execute my function in 1 click and all other clicks after the first are ignored.

```js
let count = 0;

function func() {
  if (count == 0) {
    console.log("First Click");
    let count = 1;
  } else {
    console.log("No first Click");
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="func()">Func</button>
```

(not working)

Comment: `let count = 1` to `count = 1`

Comment: You're trying to create a new variable named `count` inside the `if` block with this statement -- `let count = 1;`. If you want to utilize the already declared value, remove the `let`. Read more about the [`let` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove let keyword

Try this:

```
<script>
  count = 0;

function func() {
  if (count == 0) {
    alert("first");
    console.log("First Click");
     count = 1;
  } else {
    alert("no first");
    console.log("No first Click");
  }
}
</script>
```

https://jsbin.com/toroyiropa/edit?html,output

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest you to do something like this:

```
<button onclick="func()">Func</button>
<script>
   var enabled = true;

   function func() {
      if (enabled) {
         console.log("Do something");
         enabled = false;
      }
   }
</script>
```

To work with a persistent variable in the  context you just need to change the variable from let to var. This solution should work and also might be a little bit cleaner because I think that you probably don't need to use a counter to check if you already perform the function, it's an extra effort.

Comment: Nice answer @Alfredo Zamudio it works for me but how to set enabled back to true without page refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<button onclick="func()">Func</button>
<script>
  let count = 0;

  function func() {
    if (count == 0) {
      console.log("First Click");
      count = 1;
    } else {
      console.log("No first Click");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Explanation:
Here count is a global variable you need to change its value once to something different than your comparator i.e (count == 0).

Comment: exactly.  let  count = 1; is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

To have the count variable persist across every function call, the best way is to  use closures.

```
<button onclick="func()">Func</button>

<script>

  var clickTrack = (function() {
    var count = 0;
    return function() {
        if (count == 0) 
            console.log("First Click");
      else
            console.log("No first click");
      count++;
        return;
     }
   })();

  function func() {
        clickTrack();

  }

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question with an answer but i thought i would post my answer as it also allows for re-enabling the function.

For context this was created to follow leaflet js markers around a map and i only wanted it to snap to 1 marker at a time.

```
var focusenabled = true;
interval = null;

function focus(e) {
  if (focusenabled) {
    var i = 0;
    interval = setInterval(function () {
      mymap.setView(e.target.getLatLng());
      console.log("focus active");
    }, 2000);
    focusenabled = false;
    alert("Follow Enabled");
    console.log("Cannot follow others while following this one");
  } else {
  clearInterval(interval);
  alert("Follow Disabled");
  focusenabled = true;
  console.log("Can follow now if you want");
  }
};
```